# Browser dev tools inconsistent - whitespace in html attribute

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

Browser inspection/dev tools are inconsistent when it comes to whitespace in labels (and probably in other attributes, too, I just haven't verified).

In Chrome's Developer Tools all of the whitespace in the attribute is shown.
[image: Chrome, element with whitespace]

But in Firefox's Inspector the whitespace is condensed
[image: Firefox, element with whitespace, not all whitespace visible]

If I double click on the string, then the full string displays with all of the whitespace. 
[image: element with whitespace, all whitespace visible when double clicked]

IE 11 is different from both Firefox and Chrome: the whitespace is condensed down to one space and still only shows one space when you double click to edit it.

Shouldn't this behavior be consistent for all browsers? Is there a setting (in any of the browsers) to change the behavior?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no setting to control this.